# Powershell: Difference between exit and exit with a value

Tags: powershell

I noticed a strange behaviour in Powershell. There are two .ps1 files:

**main.ps1:**

```
echo "running exit.ps1"
$myexitcode = & ".\exit.ps1" "hello" | select -Last 1 
echo "Return code is $myexitcode"
echo "Exit code is $?"
echo "after running exit.ps1"
```

**exit.ps1:**

```
echo "processing args " $args
$script:_serverExitStatus = 9

#this is causing the program to exit completely
[System.Environment]::exit(3)

#BUT this is NOT causing the program to exit completely
#[System.Environment]::exit
```

With the above code, the process is getting completely exited and the output doesn't contain "after running exit.ps1". However, if I comment `[System.Environment]::exit(3)` and uncomment `[System.Environment]::exit`, output contains "after running exit.ps1"

I feel that exit must always exit completely. But, that's not the case with `[System.Environment]::exit`

What is the difference between these two things and which one is correct?

**Version:**

```
$PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      22000  832
```

Thank you.

Comment: `[System.Environment]::Exit` is a _method_, you need to invoke it for it to _do_ anything :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate on [Abdul Niyas P M's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73584496/45375):

In PowerShell, referencing a .NET method *without `()`* doesn't actually *invoke* the method, it prints its *signatures* (overload definitions), i.e. it performs *reflection* to show you what arguments you'd have to pass in an actual invocation:

```
PS> [System.Environment]::Exit

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static void Exit(int exitCode)
```

As you can see, the method takes an unconditional `int`-typed argument specifying the exit code to report, which implies that you *must* pass a value on invocation; if you want to signal *success*, simply use `[System.Environment]::Exit(0)`

However, I wonder if this method is really the right tool for your task, and whether use of PowerShell's `exit` statement is what you're looking for - see below.

---

- Use PowerShell's [**`exit`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.2#exit) statement to **exit the running *script***.

  - Without an argument, `0` is reported as the exit code; pass a number to set the exit code explicitly (e.g. `exit 3`).
  - *Inside* a PowerShell session, this exit code is reported in the [automatic `$LASTEXITCODE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode), *not* in the [automatic `$?` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#section-1) - the latter is an *abstract* success indicator in the form of a *Boolean* value (`$true` or `$false`), and it effectively translates a `$LASTEXITCODE` value of `0` to `$true`, and any nonzero value to `$false`.
  - When a script is invoked via *PowerShell's CLI* ([`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+):

    - With the `-File` parameter, the exit code also becomes the PowerShell process' exit code
    - With the (potentially implied) `-Command` parameter, it is the value of `$?` after the last statement executes that is translated to an exit code, with `$true` becoming `0`, and `$false` becoming `1`; thus, if the script invocation is the last statement, any nonzero exit code is effectively reported as `1`; preserving the specific exit code therefore requires appending `; exit $LASTEXITCODE` to the command string.
- Use the **[`[System.Environment]::exit($number)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.Exit)** .NET method to ***instantly* exit (terminate) the current *process*** and thereby the *whole PowerShell session*.

  - Therefore, it's best to avoid this method, unless you truly need to unconditionally terminate the entire process.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#lastexitcode) is missing the fact, that `$LASTEXITCODE` reports the exit code of scripts as well, not just _"native programs"_.

Comment: Done: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/9194. Let me know if you have suggestions to improve the proposed new wording. As you propably know, I'm not native english speaker. ;-)

Comment: @zett42 Maybe the current docs are already sufficient, because a script is no executable itself. It has to be run by `powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe` (aka native programs) which will exit with an exit code (maybe through instructions of the script).

Comment: @stackprotector No, it isn't. Scripts returning with the `exit` statement set the `$LASTEXITCODE` variable, even if directly called from another script like `.\scriptname.ps1`, so a call to `powershell.exe` or `pwsh.exe` is not involved. See demo at the github docs issue.

Answer (score 3):

[`[System.Environment]::exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=net-6.0) is a static method and requires `()` and `exitCode` parameter to do the actual work.
So `[System.Environment]::exit(3)` is the actual code that terminates the process with [status code(`3`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, ```[System.Environment]::exit``` doesn't terminate the process?

Comment: @Austin Yes that's correct!